# Tried installing service bus explorer application doesn't show in task manager?

Tags: powershell, azureservicebus, servicebus

I tried following this

https://perry230.medium.com/how-to-install-service-bus-explorer-7b06cfcb5061

this is the result [image]

as well as the curl command in git

```
curl -s https://api.github.com/repos/paolosalvatori/ServiceBusExplorer/releases/latest | grep browser_download_url | cut -d '"' -f 4
```

Comment: You're missing the *statement terminator*  after your download: `....org/install.ps1'));`. Just run the commands individually, and it should work. Right now, you're just copying and pasting it all in the console having the *tokenizer* detect errors for incomplete, or incorrect use of commands.

Comment: Also, if you want to run the equivalent of the `curl` / `grep` pipeline in PowerShell, use `(irm https://api.github.com/repos/paolosalvatori/ServiceBusExplorer/releases/latest).assets.browser_download_url`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Summarize the comments as answer for other communities reference:

As Abraham mentioned in comments, you are missing the statement terminator after download `....org/install.ps1'));`. Just run the commands individually then it can work.